# Set Text on A Button from data in parse.com IOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

How do i set the text of a button in ios with the web address stored in parse.com
i have the data ready to insert but can't work out how its done.

The data comes from parse.com
and is ready to insert

```
- (IBAction)WebAddressBtn:(id)sender {

    [sender setTitle:([self.exam objectForKey:@"website"]) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This don't seem to work
eventually i want it so when clicked it will go off to that domain from the data
i have tried a few various options but with no luck

i have done an NSlog and the result in data is 
website = "www.bbc.co.uk";

And when i open the Viewcontroller with the button on i get the default test that in in the control side of xcode and when i click it nothing happens.
(which i know would happen as there is no link there yet)

Comment: Try to add `NSLog([self.exam objectForKey:@"website"]);` just before setting the title to check if you have data.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to do? Also, when you say it doesn't work what exactly do you mean? What IS happening and what ISN'T happening, etc...

Comment: post updated with more info